# linking with boost unresolved extern link error

Tags: boost

Visual Studio 2005

I am linking with boost libraries release 1_33_1.

I keep getting this link error.

```
libboost_thread-vc80-mt-sgd-1_33_1.lib(once.obj) :error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall std::_String_base::_Xran(void)const " (?_Xran@_String_base@std@@QBEXXZ)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many thanks,

Edit ======

After recompiling the boost libraries using these switches:

```
C:\boost_1_42_0>bjam --build-dir=d:\boost_1_42 --build-type-complete --toolset=msvc-8.0 address-model=32 architecture=x86
```

I am getting some of the following errors:

```
1>msvcrtd.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR80D.dll) : error LNK2005: __wassert already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(wassert.obj)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks,

Comment: Is your project 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Was just a guess, because I once wanted to link 32 bit boost libs to a 64 bit project which doesn't work, had to compile that boost lib with 64 bit. But maybe your boost lib is build with 64 bit...

Comment: However, Just to make sure I have recompiled my boost libraries using the following: address-model=32 architecture=x86.

Comment: Correct settings, so this is not your prob.

Comment: After having recompiled I am getting some different errors. I have updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't have to set address-model and architecture explicitly if building 32 bit. Also your call has an error: `--build-type-complete` should be `--build-type=complete`. If I'm not wrong your call builds absolutely all libs, including filesystem, regex etc.

Obviously you need boost::thread only, so I would recommend to try this call:

```
C:\boost_1_42_0>bjam --build-dir=d:\boost_1_42 --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc-8.0 --with-thread
```

But I don't think that will solve your prob but you could give it a try.

My guess is that you somehow mixed /MD and /MT in the project settings.

See these links: [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937937/how-to-avoid-error-lnk2005-already-defined-stdlib-functions-when-compiling), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117452/visual-studio-linking-error-lnk2005-and-lnk2020)

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is that your project is linking to the static debug version of the C++ runtime, which causes the static debug boost thread library to be linked and is also linking to another static library which was dynamically linked to the C++ runtime.

---

*The `sgd` tag in `libboost_thread-vc80-mt-sgd-1_33_1.lib` means that the boost thread library you're linking with was built against the static debug version of the C++ runtime.*